# How to display the outerHTML of an element as a content of another one element?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, outerhtml

I want to "print" the result of `outerHTML` directly to the webpage but it writes the result of `outerHTML` insted of the "code".

Well, it's easy to show it to the `console.log` or to the `alert` window but I want to write it into the page.

```
document.getElementById("oneId").innerHTML = 
   "The outerHTML of oneId is :" +document.getElementById("anotherId").outerHTML;
```

The result must be:

```
The outerHTML of oneId is : <div id="oneId"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("oneId").textContent = 
     "The outerHTML of oneId is :" + document.getElementById("anotherId").outerHTML;
```

If you use `.innerHTML`, then the assigning string will be rendered as a html elements not pure text.

Comment: @blluch Glad to help! :)

Comment: @blluch I wonder, why did you remove your accept for this answer? Am i mussing anything that you want me to explain? :)